# SQLAlchemy, how many rows were commited on last commit

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to know how many rows were commited on the last commit on a SQLAlchemy Session? For instance, if I had just inserted 2 rows, I wish to know that there were 2 rows inserted,  etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at `session.new`, `.dirty`, and `.deleted` to see what objects will be committed, but that doesn't necessarily represent the number of rows, since those objects may set extra rows in a many-to-many association, polymorphic table, etc.